# How can I get the ascii characters from a string in Erlang

Tags: erlang, ascii, string-concatenation

I know i could get the ascii character from one letter just like this:

```
>Letter = "a",
>hd(Letter).
>97
```

But I need something like this, where all the ascii characters are concatenated:

```
>Letter = "abc",
>hd(Letter).
>979899
```

Besides that, I know the following fuction "returns" a list with all the ascii characters, but I can not assign it to a variable.

```
>io: format ( "~ w" [ "abc"]).
>[97,98,99]
```

Comment: You want a single integer `979899` for `"abc"`? Note that `"abc" == [97, 98, 99]` in Erlang.

Comment: Maybe you want io_lib:format/2: http://erlang.org/doc/man/io_lib.html#format-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function [`lists:flatmap/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#flatmap-2):

```
> lists:flatmap(fun erlang:integer_to_list/1, "abc").
"979899"
```

It applies the given function to each element, and "flattens" the result, resulting in concatenation.